# RFT Object Inspector not responding for Mozilla web elements

Tags: rft

First I tried applying RFT scripts to Mozilla Firefox, which were working fine with IE. Scripts failed. So I tried identifying test objects using RFT test object identifier in firefox, its failed to identify even.
I guessed may be that is the issue why those scripts are failed. It will be more helpful if anybody help me out on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What version of RFT and FF  are you  using ?

Browser  requires enablement    for FF it would mean that  we need enable it from RFT which will install an  add-on  /extension in Firefox  that you can see under Tool> add-ons  in FF.
Also we need to enable the java that is being used by the browser.